# Does ToDictionary() create a copy or a reference?

Tags: c#, multithreading

The MSDN Documentation on [ToDictionary()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't say much about how it actually works. I'm wondering whether it creates a copy of the dictionary and its elements, or just reuses the same references and enumerator.

For instance, if I have a ConcurrentDictionary `c`, and I create a Dictionary `d` by invoking `c.ToDictionary(...)`, can I use (think `foreach`) `d` independently (in a thread-safe manner) of threads updating `c`?

As a matter of fact, when I do this, I am getting:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

...when serializing `d`.

Comment: It just enumerates your IEnumerable with a foreach statement, if you ask about that, But enumerating ConcurrentDictionary is thread-safe and should not throw exception you mentioned.

Comment: No, what I'm asking is: if I enumerate over the dictionary created from a ConcurrentDictionary, is that thread-safe when the original ConcurrentDictionary gets updated?

Comment: They are not related in any way - when you add new item to ConcurrentDictionary your another dictonary is not affected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a shallow copy of your collection.

You can see this behavior in the [.NET Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,a6091311eadfdd8a):

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (keySelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
    if (elementSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
    Dictionary<TKey, TElement> d = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in source) d.Add(keySelector(element), elementSelector(element));
    return d;
}
```

As you can see, it creates a new `Dictionary`, iterates over your collection and adds all elements to it, applying the selector functions. So if you update your original collection, the dictionary won't be updated, and vice versa.